# How to select a list of all the attachments for specific invoice by using QBO attachable query API

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I added one new attachable file and reference it to invoice. Now I am editing that file and want to remove that already attachable file if any. So how can I select the attachable query so I get the attachable file list for specific invoice.

I tried to use QBO API attachable query like `select * from attachable where AttachableRef.EntityRef.value = <QB invoice Id>` but getting 400 error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying an EntityRef you need to specifiy the type and value.  So your query would be:

select * from attachable where AttachableRef.EntityRef.value = '' and AttachableRef.EntityRef.type = 'Invoice'

Note: you also need to bound the qb invoice if with single quotes.